# Referencing image resources in addon data folder

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have an image in the data folder: `data\img\myimage.jpg`. I want to reference it in a content script. More over, I want to alter the DOM of the host page (the page where the content script is injected to) by putting that image there.

I tried to follow what Jeff says here: http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/01/11/sdk-1-4-known-issue-with-hard-coding-resource-uris/ (because I didn't find any other references to that issue), but nothing worked.

What is the URL I need to use in the page in order to reference an image from the add-on's folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Jeff mentioned in that post, you can use the [self](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/self.html) module to get a URL to your images in the `data` directory. To get that information in a content script, you can either pass it in via [messages](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html#Communicating%20With%20Content%20Scripts)(page-mod example here, but similar to all content scripts) to communicate with the script, or if you're inlining your content script, can just 'bake' it in. The `self` module won't be available in the content script, but passing in a string is fine.

```
let url = self.data.url('img/myimage.png');
pageMod({
  contentScript: 'var url = ' + url + ';' + 'console.log(url);',
  include: '*.mozilla.org'
})
```

Comment: Pretty please, don't ever eval() concatenated code like this.  (Also the code is broken due to missing quotes). It is error prone, often mixed with some nice security vulnerabilities, hard to read and maintain. Use message passing.

Comment: Also, you can pass data into a content script on creation using the page-mod's 'contentScriptOptions' property: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html#API Reference

Answer (score 7):

The data folder is available in main.js and you can pass that url as a content script option.

To preview the url in the console from main.js:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
console.log(data.url('img/myimage.jpg'));
```

To pass the url to the content script in main.js:

```
var image_url = data.url('img/myimage.jpg');
...
contentScriptFile: data.url('myScript.js'),
contentScriptOptions: {"image_url" : image_url}
...
```

To view the url from the content script:

```
alert(self.options.image_url);
```